# Send email with Sendgrid on a shared hosting

Tags: email, hosting, cpanel, sendgrid, exim

I have my websites hosted in a shared hosting where CPanel and EXIM are installed.

My goal is to send all outgoing emails via Sendgrid, as explained in this article: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/exim/

I cannot edit the main EXIM config file because it would affect all the users of the server, so I was wandering if it is possible to add a configuration file in my local /home/etc folder in order to use a different EXIM config for my websites only.

I tried to add an exim.config.local file in my etc folder, but nothing changes...
Do you know if there is any way to achieve my goal? Maybe a local EXIM alternative?

I can use PUTTY to wget files, but apt-get install is not available.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `.include_if_exists $home/exim.conf` in the main config and it will only load a users config if it is present in its homedir. That way it won't affect the other users of the server.

Comment: but I am in a shared hosting, I cannot modify the main config file... This is why I was looking for the possibility to add a local config file that bypasses the main one, as you can do for instance with the .htaccess files

Comment: Can you access the main config and read its content? Can you share your hoster? Would be easier to find a solution/documentation then. Or maybe try to find an alternative, send mails directly via php or switch to vps and setup your own environment, which can be as cheap as 2$ a month